# What started barons being represented more negatively in literature?

Tags: history-of-literature

I've noticed that barons more often are portrayed negatively in comparison to lords or royalty (though the latter is a mixed bag). Come to think of it, I can't think of a baron portrayed in a positive light. Examples include:

- Baron Vengeous from Skullduggery pleasant
- Baron Zemo from Marvel Comics
- The Bloody Baron from Harry Potter is the Slytherin house ghost with a dark history
- There appears to be plenty more on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_nobility#Barons_and_baronesses)

What started this trend of Barons denoting bad people?

Comment: See TVTROPES WARNING https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AristocratsAreEvil

Comment: There are plenty of good barons in literature.  Baron Munchausen , for a start. Or the protagonist in Ruddigore, under a curse to commit a crime every day. He commits the most trivial acts he can think of, until he breaks the curse. Sir Percy Blakeney (baronet). And John Creasey's  thief turned detective, The Baron.

Comment: Baron Valdemar in Mercedes Lackey's books, of course.

Comment: To be pedantic, in the UK a Baron _is_ a Lord! Most of the ones in the Wikipedia list are European and/or from imaginary countries.